# Android Wear: How does it work an activity life cycle?

Tags: android, android-activity, wear-os, android-sensors, activity-lifecycle

I made a wearable app with activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("WEAR", "CREATE");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });
    SensorManager  sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor hrs = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    sm.registerListener(hrListener, hrs, 3);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.i("WEAR", "RESTORE");
        // ... get previous sensor data from the bundle

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i("WEAR", "STOP");
    super.onStop();
    sm.unregisterListener(hrListener, hrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("WEAR", "DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("WEAR", "SAVE");
    // ... save sensor data in the bundle
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

private SensorEventListener hrListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {
        final float hearRate = event.values[0];
        Log.i("SENSOR", hearRate);
        mTextView.setText(Float.toString(hearRate));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```

When it starts I see the flow of data from the sensor.
After a while the screen return on the clock watchface and the Log says STOP and SAVE on my app debug flow. I relaunch the app but the bundle is null and I lost all my data saved in the bundle. `onDestroy` is never called so why I don't get any bundle?
It's a Gear Live.

Comment: Do you have special setting for activity launch mode?

Comment: No, I have the default setting created by Android Studio

Comment: you need to provide more information. Manifest and what your class extends.

Comment: it extends AppCompatActivity and Manifest is the default one of a project creation

Answer (score 2):

The action to close the wear app should be `slide` from left to right to close it. You will see `onDestroy` is called.
If you just press the button ( I only have a moto 360 1st gen. i.e. the side button), it is like just put the app off the foreground. So just `onStop` and `onStart` pair is called. Hope this late answer will still help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add finish the app by swiping left to right or by long press (Need to code for the same). Once finish is called, onDestroy will get called.